# Programatically setting the text colour of a label in GWT

Tags: gwt

How do I set the colour of the text in  a label programatically.
Here is my latest attempt.

```
    public void setFontColour(String colour )
{
    label.getElement().getStyle().setFontStyle( Style.FontStyle.valueOf("bluetext") );
}
```

I just want to make a call to the setColour method but everything I google for attempts to do this via CSS.  In this instance I want to set it via Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
label.getElement().getStyle().setColor("red");
```

Comment: That simple, thnx  I was obsessed with font style